# Multiprocessing map unorderable?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, typeerror

I have an operation using a dictionnary that I want to parallelize, but multiprocessing.map is causing me headaches

```
def dict_segmentor(dictionnary,n_processes):
    print("len dictionnary")    
    print(len(dictionnary))
    if len(dictionnary) < n_processes:
        seg_size = len(dictionnary)
    else:
        seg_size = len(dictionnary) // n_processes
    print("segmenting dictionnary")
    print("seg_size "+str(seg_size))
    print("len(dictionnary) "+str(len(dictionnary)))
    itemlist=list(dictionnary.items())
    seg_ranges = [dict(itemlist[s:s+seg_size]) for s in range(1,  len(dictionnary)+1, seg_size)]
    print("finished")
    return seg_ranges

def multiprocess_calc(n_processes, dictionnary,struc):
    dictionnary=dictionnary
    struc=struc

    seg_ranges1 = dict_segmentor(dictionnary,n_processes)
    #this is invoked to break the dict to be passed into dicts into a list. Works as expected
    print("seg_range_check")    
    print("seg_ranges1 {}".format(type(seg_ranges1)))#Returns a dict as expected
    print("seg_ranges1 {}".format(type(seg_ranges1[0])))#Returns a list as expected
    print("seg_ranges1 {}".format(len(seg_ranges1)))    #Returns expected len=1
    print("seg_ranges1 {}".format(len(seg_ranges1[0]))) #Returns expected len

    processes = multiprocessing.Pool(n_processes)
    print("Mapping Building")

    processes.map(Builder, seg_ranges1,1)

def main():
    file_multiprocess  = 'pref_multiprocess.csv'
    n_CPUs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    n_processes  = n_CPUs-1
    print("\nNumber of CPUs detected:", n_CPUs)
    multiprocess_calc(n_processes, file_multiprocess,struc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is complete Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-d0279721826c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('Pyscript.py', wdir='C:/Python Scripts')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "Pyscript.py", line 1033, in <module>
    main()

  File "Pyscript.py", line 1025, in main
    multiprocess_calc(n_processes, dictionnary,struc)

  File "Pyscript.py", line 911, in multiprocess_calc
    processes.map(Builder, seg_ranges1,1)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value

 TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

I don't understand, even by reading this carefully (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing).
Each chunk is a dict, so it should be sent through map to the builder.
But instead I get that stupid error and the traceback doesn't help. I looked into the code of *pool.py* but no luck,
and my builder is not involved since its first operation (a control printing) is not even displayed. The builder function seems to be totally ignored (and there is not even a syntax error)
So I conclude this is a problem with map.
In case I would have misunderstood the multiprocessing.map function and that it would first make a chunk, then iterate over it to apply map on each sub sub element, what function of multiprocessing could I use? Apply use only one thread. That would mean I should do this manually?
Please feel free to correct my code and give me some insights. Thanks by advance

Edit: here is the builder function:

```
def Builder(dictionary,struc=struc):
#def Builder(keys, dictionary=dictionary,struc=struc):  #Alternative
#Note, I even tried to use only the keys, passing the dictionary from a global variable but it didn't work
    print("Building Tree")    #Not even displayed
    print("type dictionary"+str(type(dictionary)))
    frags=0
    try:
        if True:
            print("Building")  
            #for id in keys: #Alternative
            for id in dictionary:
                seq=dictionary[id]
                for i in range(3):
                    frags+=1
                    if len(seq)<=3:
                        break
                    seq=seq[i:-i]
                    struc.append(seq)
                print("Number of frags found {}".format(frags))
    except TypeError as e:
        print (e)
        print ("error in Builder")
```

Comment: your `dict_segmentor` creates and returns a list, so I can't see how `seg_ranges1` could ever be a dict. There are also a few variables thet aren't defined anywhere (trie, train_seqs).  Is this the complete code?  Also, iterating over a dict yields its _keys_, so passing a dict as `iterable` to `Pool.map` would result the worker function to be called with each keys as argument, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. seg_ranges1 is a list of dictionaries, which is what I wanted, since actually I expected to use my builder function over each chunk of the original dictionary, that's why I put the chunks in the list seg_ranges1, so map would break up the list one chunk/dict at a time and sent it to builder function. So am I mistaken about map? (once obtaining each dict, it will iterate as python map() would do? if it is the case, what could I use to only send the chunks to builder() in parallel? Apply doesn't seem to be fitting... (I corrected the remnants of anonymization).

Comment: If it's a list of dict, then yes, map will invoke Builder with one dict as argument. I can only guess that there is something wrong with your Builder function, maybe you should also post that code.

Comment: It is a list of dicts, I print everything before the multiprocessing.map line to ensure it. So I am positive it is, and you can see by yourself with the code too. Well, I am going to post it, but as I said before, it's very first line is not even reached. As you can see in the traceback, its inner lines are not even quoted. So it's puzzling.

Comment: Hm, that error would make sense if you were passing a list as `chunksize`, but your stacktrace doesn't support that, so I can't really think of anything else here. Really strange.

Comment: Well, the stacktrace was useless. I broke the code, put everything in the main scope, and definitely print everything at each step, pausing everything. My dict segmentor was correct. What wasn't is that the original dict was built by adding up multiple dicts, and one contained a tuple as value instead of a list, because out of Java habit, I put a comma after the list comprehension made to generate it. Then it was breaking when calling the empty part of the tuple. 2 days lost for that. I just hate myself sometimes:)

Comment: How could I close this question?

Comment: If you don't think the resolution of the question wil benefit someone else you can always delete it, or otherwise you can answer it yourself and mark your own answer as accepted